# Execute program with hit on enter after write text and remove written

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I'm new,  I found examples here, but nothing works proper for me.

I'm just trying execute my program second way, but not sure how to figure out.

I want write some phrase in textBox1, then hit on enter, remove written phrase from textBox1, make some calculations and only then  show this text in textBox2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace XX_TEXTBOX_TEST
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }    
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
            textBox2.AppendText("OK!");   
        }
    }
}
```

if I go this way:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace XX_TEXTBOX_TEST
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }   
        private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {    
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                textBox2.AppendText("OK!");
            }                   
        }
    }
}
```

I got error:

> `Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'Form1' does not contain a definition for
>   'textBox1_TextChanged' and no extension method 'textBox1_TextChanged'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'Form1' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  XX_TEXTBOX_TEST
>   C:\FOLDER\Form1.Designer.cs   42  Active

And:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Suppression State
>   Message       The designer cannot process unknown name
>   'textBox1_TextChanged' at line 42.  The code within the method
>   'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer and should not be
>   manually modified.  Please remove any changes and try opening the
>   designer again. C:\FOLDER\Form1.Designer.cs   43

Comment: `TextChanged` is only trigger when the text changed. you must use keydown event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void  textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            //your function 
        }
    }
```

you must use KeyDown event of textbox

Comment: Yes but if I do it this way, my form gives an error, and I can’t find where is the textBox1_TextChange still exist. Or I must do it with new one, but where? I use Visual Studio 2015 what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @MolC check on `form1.designer.cs` file you can find function declaration. or simply clicking on error it will automatically go to that file